# Почему повторное использование animate( { scrollTop: scrollTop }, 500 ) скроллит куда то не туда?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вобщем, делаю скролл внутри таблицы, код привожу снизу, почему когда я первый раз кликаю, все ок, скроллит куда нужно и логично наверно, что когда я кликну повторный раз, то по сути никуда ничего не должно будет скроллится ибо я уже нахожусь на нужной позиции. Однако у меня при повторном клике происходит скролл вобще в какие то рандомные места.

```js
 $('#sc-wrap > .sc-controller').each( function(i, elem){
  $(elem).attr('data-target', 'sc-position' + (i + 1) );
 });

 $('.sc-controller').click( function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  var scrollTop = $('#'+target).offset().top;
  $('.sc-data').animate({
   scrollTop: scrollTop
  }, 500)
 })
```

```css
.sc-data{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sc-wrap{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 11;
}
#sc-wrap > .sc-controller{
  background: #e61a1a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .45s;
}
#sc-wrap > .sc-controller:hover{ background: #f33; }
#sc-wrap > .sc-controller:last-child{ margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="sc-wrap">
    <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 1</div>
    <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 2</div>
    <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="component sc-data">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Наименование</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr id="sc-position1">
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="sc-position2">
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="sc-position3">
              <td>test</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Кстати такое чувство, что при повторном клике отскролливает на предыдущую страницу

Comment: Составьте [mcve], нам ни к чему знать про арматуру и видеть её стили, если проблема не в арматуре, а в animate

Comment: UPD: сделал воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала несколько замечаний к вашему примеру.
Во первых, этот код работает не корректно потому что [метод](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) `.offset().top` возвращает расстояние до верхней границе документа. Ваш код был бы верным если бы скролл находился на документе, но у вас он находится в таблице. Это станет заметно когда в таблице вместо `test` вы добавите `test1`, `test2`, `test3`. По этому для начала нужно получить расстояние от верхней границы таблицы до нужного элемента.

```
 var offsetAnchor = $('#' + target).offset().top;
 var offsetTable = $('.sc-data').offset().top;
 var offset = offsetAnchor - offsetTable;
```

Далее нужно учесть что при скролле offset().top у элемента может быть отрицательным

```
 var offsetAnchor = $('#' + target).offset().top;
 var offsetTable = $('.sc-data').offset().top;
 var scrollWrapper = $('.sc-data').scrollTop();
 var offset = offsetAnchor - offsetTable + scrollWrapper;
```

Пример рабочего кода

```js
$('#sc-wrap > .sc-controller').each(function(i, elem) {
  $(elem).attr('data-target', 'sc-position' + (i + 1));
});

$('.sc-controller').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  var offsetAnchor = $('#' + target).offset().top;
  var offsetTable = $('.sc-data').offset().top;
  var scrollWrapper = $('.sc-data').scrollTop();
  $('.sc-data').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetAnchor - offsetTable + scrollWrapper
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
.sc-data {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sc-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 11;
}

#sc-wrap>.sc-controller {
  background: #e61a1a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  ;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .45s;
}

#sc-wrap>.sc-controller:hover {
  background: #f33;
}

#sc-wrap>.sc-controller:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sc-wrap">
  <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 1</div>
  <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 2</div>
  <div class="sc-controller">Позиция 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="component sc-data">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Наименование</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="sc-position1">
          <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="sc-position2">
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="sc-position3">
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```